# (SELECT * ...) UNION (SELECT * ...) in a specific script

Tags: php, pdo, union

Here is a piece of code in pdo:

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `games_server` WHERE `full_address` = :fulladdress LIMIT 1");
$result->execute(array('fulladdress'=>$address));
```

What I need to do is to union this select with another table like

```
(SELECT * FROM `games_server` WHERE `full_address` = :fulladdress LIMIT 1) UNION (SELECT * FROM `x_servers` WHERE `full_address` = :fulladdress LIMIT 1)
```

, but there seems to be a syntax error and also these tables have a different number of columns, so it seems impossible.

My question is if there's any way around this. I've looked around and tried a bunch of variants and nothing worked.

Does anybody have any clues how to make it work?

Comment: Thing you have to use `:fulladdress1` and `:fulladdress2` and bind both params.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but could you please explain how to bind them?

Comment: What does it mean, " there seems to be a syntax error"? If there is an error, what does it say?

Comment: well when I try it in phpmyadmin it says #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':fulladdress1 LIMIT 1) UNION (SELECT * FROM `x_servers_ban` WHERE `full_address`' at line 1

actual script doesn't give any errors but it just doesn't work

Comment: `array(':fulladdress1'=>$address,':fulladdress2'=>$address)` like that

Comment: Note that you cannot use union query with different number of columns. select only equal columns from both tables

Comment: Thank you everyone. This is the solution: (SELECT `full_address` as `full_address_result` FROM `games_server` WHERE `full_address` = :fulladdress LIMIT 1) UNION (SELECT `full_address` as `full_address_result` FROM `x_servers` WHERE `full_address` = :fulladdress LIMIT 1)